# What is the meaning of the '2' in the Eclipse console header: MyApp (2) [Java Application]

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I'm writing a Swing application in Eclipse, and I just noticed that, after I launch the application, the Eclipse console header has a '2' in parentheses, as in:

MyApp (2) [Java Application] C:\Program Files\Java ...

Whenever I've used Eclipse before, I only noticed the number '1' there.

Does anyone know the meaning of these numbers?

Comment: You probably have two instances of the app running simultaneously.

Comment: As far as I can tell, I only have a single instance running.  I've even shut down Eclipse and restarted my program for the first time, and it still has a "(2)" there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the name of the `Run Configuration` for the application. Eclipse makes up a name for this configuration each time you run a new program, if there is already an application with the app name it adds (1), (2) ... to the name.

Open `Run > Run Configurations` (or `Debug Configurations`) and you will see the list of configurations that Eclipse has. You can edit the names if you want or delete out of date configurations.

Answer (score 1):

As by default the action of clicking on close will not exit that java process, hence even you `closed` that java swing application, the java process still running.
That is the reason of `2`appear on your eclipse since there exists 2 java swing processes on your machine.
To quit that the disposed process, you need to click on the red square button on `terminal` tab.
Or I will suggest you to set default Close Action with `exit`.

Comment: Even if I run the program for the first time, and even while it is running, it still has the 2.  I also coded event handlers for an exit button and for window closing, so I don't think that is the issue.  Is it normal for it two show that more than 1 process is running?  My program uses Quartz and connects to a database, so maybe one of those is the extra process that is showing up?

Comment: @Bri have you clear previous application all? I think I should be the issue.

Comment: Yes, when I open up Eclipse for the first time and then start my application, it still has a '2'.  There are no other applications or versions of that application running.

Comment: @Bri what about run that application again without closing eclipse? does the number become `3`?

Comment: No, if I quit the application and then start it again, it still says 2.

Comment: I also checked Windows Task Manager and only one version of the application is running at a time, but it still says 2 (?)

Comment: @Bri Do you named it with (2) yourself? what about restart your PC

Comment: No, I did not name it with (2) myself.  I also just restarted my PC, restarted Eclipse and started the application and it still says (2).